# Uable to open swagger ui page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui

Thanks in advance .

Below is the security config class and swagger config class. Have been trying to integrate swagger for a ver long time, but i m failing.

When I am trying to open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html it gives me Whitelabel Error Page.

my pom.xml file contains the following dependencies :-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    private static final String[] AUTH_LIST = {
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { //todo-ant matcher changes
        http.cors().and().csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_LIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**",
                        "/api/v1/user/create",
                        "/api/v1/vendor-responses/intro",
                        "/api/v1/timetable/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/course/**").hasAnyAuthority(TEACHER.name(), SUPERUSER.name())
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPERUSER.name())
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAnyAuthority(TEACHER.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

````
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    /**
     * Method to set paths to be included through swagger
     *
     * @return Docket
     */
    @Bean
    public Docket configApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.apnatuitionmaster.controller"))
                .build();
    }


    /**
     * Method to set swagger info
     *
     * @return ApiInfoBuilder
     */
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("")
                .description("")
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}```

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmfM2.png
````

Comment: Are you authenticated when accessing swagger?

Comment: I m white listing the url. Have created a auth list where I have provided some swagger resources and then permitting this list. Access isn't denied, a white label page( page not found) is coming.